# How to handle one class used in multiple db contexts for one database in EF code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am trying to make some module class library APIs that use EF in my repository layer. For any of that to work I need a dbcontext class in each class library. But what happens when I need one class to be referenced in each module? Take for example I have a users module whose db contexts includes:

- Users
- Groups
- Roles

Then I have a locations module that includes:

- Buildings
- Locations
- Rooms

Then say a third module for Equipment which has:

- Equipment
- Equipment Types
- Work Orders

The latter two still need references to users, which is pretty much integral to every module. But I can't add two separate user classes to two contexts pointing to the same db, it's possible they could become out of sync then. So the obvious solution there is just have the latter 2 modules require the user module, and any class in those modules that needs the user just references the userID. This would break normalization though since it wouldn't be a foreign key so I am not sure how good that idea is.

Another possibility that popped into my head was having each module's dbcontext use an interface, and allow the person using the module to declare their own dbcontext and implement all those members, but I'm not sure that will work either.

I basically just want to make a collection of class library modules that define a common set of classes and API calls available to other programmers, while using EF as the base with the intent that this would all be stored in one DB. But I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that with how DbContexts work. What happens when you have multiple modules requiring the same object?

Comment: Not sure it's exactly what you need, but see the article by Lehrman referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454395/bounded-contexts-and-ef-code-first-how-to-put-them-together

Comment: That answer looks interesting, but I can foresee problems when they try to  update migrations for each context. Perhaps something like that is workable though.

Comment: She gets around that with the "uber-model" mentioned in the article. The other contexts don't do migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three contexts you are representing typically match to [Bounded Contexts](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) as designed in the [Domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), as rightly pointed by Steeve.

There are obviously multiple ways to implement this scenario and each one has their pros and cons.

I am suggesting two approaches to respect the best practices of the Domain-driven design and to have a great flexibility.

**Approach #1: Soft-separation**

I define a `User` class in the first bounded context and an interface representing a reference to a user in the second bounded context.

Let's define the user:

```
class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Other models that reference a user implements `IUserRelated`:

```
interface IUserRelated
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    Guid UserId { get; }
}
```

The design pattern recommends to not directly link two entities from two separated bounded contexts, but store their respective reference instead.

The `Building` class looks like:

```
class Building : IUserRelated
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the `Building` model knows only the reference of a `User`. Nonetheless, the interface acts a foreign key and constraints the value inserted into this `UserId` property.

Let's now define the db contexts...

```
class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    static BaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected BaseContext() : base("Demo")
    {

    }
}

class UserContext : BaseContext<UserContext>
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

class BuildingContext : BaseContext<BuildingContext>
{
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

And the db context to initialize the database:

```
class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext() : base("Demo")
    {
    }
}
```

And finally, the code that creates a user and a building:

```
// Defines some constants
const string userName = "James";
var userGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

// Initialize the db
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(true);
}

// Create a user
using (var userContext = new UserContext())
{
    userContext.Users.Add(new User {Name = userName, Id = userGuid});
    userContext.SaveChanges();
}

// Create a building linked to a user
using (var buildingContext = new BuildingContext())
{
    buildingContext.Buildings.Add(new Building {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Location = "Switzerland", UserId = userGuid});
    buildingContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Approach #2: Hard-separation**

I define one `User` class in each of the bounded context. An interface enforces the common properties. This approach is illustrated by Martin Fowler as follows:

[image]

User bounded context:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : BaseContext<UserContext>
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Building bounded context:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class BuildingContext : BaseContext<BuildingContext>
{
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, this is totally acceptable to have a `Users` property in the `BuildingContext`, as a user exists in the context of a building as well.

Usage:

```
    // Defines some constants
    const string userName = "James";
    var userGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Create a user
    using (var userContext = new UserContext())
    {
        userContext.Users.Add(new User { Name = userName, Id = userGuid });
        userContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Create a building linked to a user
    using (var buildingContext = new BuildingContext())
    {
        var userReference = buildingContext.Users.First(user => user.Id == userGuid);

        buildingContext.Buildings.Add(new Building { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Location = "Switzerland", User = userReference });
        buildingContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Playing with EF migrations is really easy. The migration script for the User bounded context (generated by EF):

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Users");
    }
}
```

The migration script for the Building bounded context (generate by EF). I have to remove the creation of the table `Users`, as the other bounded context has the responsibility of creating it. You can still check if the table doesn't exist before creating it for a modular approach:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Buildings",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Location = c.String(),
                    User_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Buildings", "User_Id", "dbo.Users");
        DropIndex("dbo.Buildings", new[] { "User_Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.Users");
        DropTable("dbo.Buildings");
    }
}
```

Apply the `Upgrade-Database` for the two contexts and you database is ready !

**EDIT for OP request about adding new properties in the class `User`.**

When a bounded context adds a new property to the class `User`, it incrementally adds a new column under the hood. It does not redefine the whole table. This is why this implementation is very versatile as well.

Here is an example of migration script where a new property `Accreditation` is added to the class `User` in the bounded context `Building`:

```
public partial class Accreditation : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Accreditation", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "Accreditation");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it still requires a third overarching "all in one" context. to perform migrations on. this sort of defeats the module-esque appracoh of picking and choosing what you want. You'd still have to make your own context and stick all the objects in it. This wouldn't be so bad, except that you already had your other specific contexts.

Comment: Hey @DOTang, I edited my answer to provide the approach *Hard-separation*, that enables you to play freely with EF migration scripts.

Comment: Hey that looks pretty good, but, how would you handle something like say the building module's user has a property and/or relationship that isn't in the Users module? I assume it would work still but you would have to run the migration on the building module after the user module, but it seems like it would break down if you have a third module that also referenced users that also requires it's own special properties on user? Which in turn the answer would be to use the huge overarching context again right?

Comment: The cases you are describing is perfectly handled by the *hard-separation* approach. Any additional property bound to the user in the Building bounded context has to be inserted into the class `User` in the Building bounded context. If a third module also needs to own some other properties for a user, then this third module will have a class `User` with those properties as well. I've added in my answer a diagram made by Martin Fowler describing visually two bounded contexts and how that are connected together.

Comment: But wouldn't when applying the third migration, it would remove the user specific properties from the second module's migration? Assuming both second and third had unique user specific properties. Say the building context's user has a reference to a new "Salary" object. and the third context's user has a reference to a new "Status" object. If I run the second and then third migration. Would it not delete the salary object?

Comment: Err wait, I think I can answer that as "no". Because the third migrations script has no knowledge of the Salary object so there would be no line to remove it. Am I correct?

Comment: Of course this is possible! The migration script behaves incrementally (this is very powerful). I've edited my answer, check at the bottom.

Comment: @ZenLulz I know this is an old post, but can you clarify something in the hard separation for me?  You mention "An interface enforces the common properties"  How exactly is that accomplished?

Answer (score -2):

1. There is a very good explanation for DDD, you can find here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/january/data-points-shrink-ef-models-with-ddd-bounded-contexts
2. But I myself using a very simple approach for 2 separated databases:

- define one data model for all classes,
- define one base context for all classes,
- generate with migration tool 2 separated identical databases each with a own context
- replicate shared data from database 1 to database 2 =>
  It's may be a very primitive approach but works stable !

Comment: That's not going to work for any online system and database replication is far too complex a solution for the problem.